# flutter error on ubuntu: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flutter, ubuntu-16.04

This are the codes of my command line. There are many paths for my flutter SDK to make sure of them is the correct path.

```
anonymous@guardianOP:~$ echo $PATH

/home/anonymous/Home/Desktop/flutter/bin:/Desktop/Flutter/bin:/home/anonymous/.local/bin:/Desktop/Flutter/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

anonymous@guardianOP:~$ flutter

flutter: command not found

anonymous@guardianOP:~$
```

This is the code of my bash profile

```
export PATH=~/Home/Desktop/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

This is the link to the image of my directory to the flutter SDK

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE3P3.png]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try going to the flutter installation path and try running flutter command to make sure flutter is installed.

Comment: I went to the bin directory and typed flutter, it didn't work.

Comment: How did you install flutter? Did you download the flutter zip file or did you use curl to download the flutter?  If the dart sdk is not downloaded is there any firewall that is preventing from download?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file. Just now I ran ./flutter in the bin directory. It's downloaded and it works there. However it doesn't run when I leave the directory.

Comment: Then now you can run 
        export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Desktop/flutter/bin

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is not executable.
You could make it executable with:

```
chmod u+x /home/anonymous/Home/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter
```